# docker exec giving different PID when wrapping command in $()

Tags: bash, docker

The following happened:

```
$ docker exec my_container /bin/bash -l -c "pgrep -f 'java'"
7
$ docker exec my_container /bin/bash -l -c "echo $(pgrep -f 'java')"
11792
```

Those PIDs are respectively inside the container and outside the container.

And I don't see why it's happening. How com a simple $() escapes the docker exec context?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Bash has first dibs. It expands variables and commands in subshells before passing the info to your docker exec. This is the equivalent of running `docker exec my_container /bin/bash -l -c "echo 11792"`

Comment: (Try putting `echo` in front of each of the two commands, just to see how the shell is expanding them.)

Comment: Instead of using `echo`, I'd recommend `set -x` (as a separate command) before running these to see what they're doing (and `set +x` afterward, to turn it off). `echo` prints things *after* they've been fully parsed (including quote and escape removal), which can be very misleading. (OTOH, `-x` mode prints commands as they execute with *equivalent* quoting/escaping, which can be differently confusing. Sigh.)